# Trying to get key value as a column in a table from JSON

Tags: python

Python noob here. I have a dictionary being created with a for loop API call. I'm getting the data back fine, but now I need to create a table from it, with the first column being the key(zip code).

```
results = dict()
for each_zip in all_zips_dedup:
    r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=' + str(each_zip) + ',' + country_code + '&units=imperial' + '&appid=' + api_key)
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    results.update({each_zip: data})
```

[image]

Example of first record of dictionary:

```
{92064: {'coord': {'lon': -117.04, 'lat': 32.98}, 'weather': [{'id': 800, 'main': 'Clear', 'description': 'clear sky', 'icon': '01d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 69.66, 'feels_like': 64.33, 'temp_min': 66.2, 'temp_max': 72, 'pressure': 1019, 'humidity': 22}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': {'speed': 2.39, 'deg': 106}, 'clouds': {'all': 1}, 'dt': 1606932174, 'sys': {'type': 1, 'id': 5686, 'country': 'US', 'sunrise': 1606919677, 'sunset': 1606956087}, 'timezone': -28800, 'id': 0, 'name': 'Poway', 'cod': 200},...
```

I guess I have 2 troubles with this:

1. How do I get a table saved to csv from my JSON with a column containing the key values?
2. How can I get one column for different desired levels within the dictionary (i.e. - for `'weather'` I would just want a column `for 'id','main','description','icon'`)

I'm probably just in way over my head, but I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post, please don't post images, post actual data. It's not clear what your asking in Q1. If you have data and can parse into a pandas dataframe, you can use pandas.to_csv to write to excel. there are other libraries that can help as well.

However, import into pandas doesn't give a straightforward parsing.

```
import pandas as pd

results = {92064: {'coord': {'lon': -117.04, 'lat': 32.98}, 'weather': [{'id': 800, 'main': 'Clear', 'description': 'clear sky', 'icon': '01d'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 69.66, 'feels_like': 64.33, 'temp_min': 66.2, 'temp_max': 72, 'pressure': 1019, 'humidity': 22}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': {'speed': 2.39, 'deg': 106}, 'clouds': {'all': 1}, 'dt': 1606932174, 'sys': {'type': 1, 'id': 5686, 'country': 'US', 'sunrise': 1606919677, 'sunset': 1606956087}, 'timezone': -28800, 'id': 0, 'name': 'Poway', 'cod': 200}}

df = pd.DataFrame(results).T # T is to transpose the data
df.to_csv('filename.csv') # there are other options when writing csv files so check out the pandas docs
```

to get further down the chain you can do this:

```
results[92064]['weather']

In [138]: results[92064]['weather']
Out[138]: [{'id': 800, 'main': 'Clear', 'description': 'clear sky', 'icon': '01d'}]

In [141]: pd.DataFrame(results[92064]['weather'])
Out[141]:
    id   main description icon
0  800  Clear   clear sky  01d
```